# Facing problem with return Observable<boolean> Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I'm facing a problem with angular.. I created a pipe that is supposed to call another pipe and check with a loop if all the elements of an array are false.. if one is true ill return true.. I don't know why I'm not allowed to return an Observable boolean..
I have been struggling the whole day with this error.. I would really appreciate if someone could help me
The Error:

> TS2322: Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type
> 'boolean'.

```
transform(antwortElem: UiKat[]): Observable<boolean> {
      if(!antwortElem){
         return null;
      }
      return this.service.enabledState$.pipe(
         map(enabledState => {
            let enabled = false;
            Elem.forEach((antwort) => {
               if(enabledState[antwort.id] != null){
                  return enabledState[antwort.id];
               }else{
                  return true;
               }
            })

         })
      )


   }
```

Comment: You can not "early return" from a `forEach` loop.

Comment: Did you mean `some` instead of `forEach` and then return that value? `return antwortElm.some(....` ?

Comment: Maybe return of(null); will help?

Comment: I think `some` is what you're looking for, also `if(enabledState[antwort.struktur.id] != null)` is a pretty bad check, what if `enabledState[antwort.struktur.id]` is undefined? it'd return true. You should use the `!!` operator (`if (!!enabledState[antwort.struktur.id])`) or  (`if (enabledState[antwort.struktur.id])`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
transform(antwortElem: UiKategorie[]): Observable<boolean> {
  if(!antwortElem){
     return null; // this probably isn't allowed for your typings. needs to be Observable<boolean> | null
  }
  return this.iqsService.enabledStateInbearbeitung$.pipe(
     map(enabledState => {
        // for each doesn't work that way, use the some operator instead
        // some will return true if any element matches the condition
        return antwortElem.some(antwort => !!enabledState[antwort.struktur.id])
     })
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` needs to return something. In your case you did a `forEach` which should be returned

```js
 for(let antwort in antwortElem) {
               if(enabledState[antwort.struktur.id] != null){
                  return enabledState[antwort.struktur.id];
               }else{
                  return true;
               }
            })
```

The error states that you return nothing and that's why it is `void`

Comment: `forEach` returns `undefined` which would still cause a "is not assignable to type" error because `Observable<undefined>` is no the same as the expected return type `Observable<boolean>`

Comment: Ah you're right!